How do I clear Android Studio Cached App Data between test runs
I am having problems debugging an Android App using Android Studio. For some of my test runs I want a clean install but I am finding that data from a previous test run keeps reappearing. This is a hybrid app mostly using Javascript with a Java wrapper to handle location, compass, camera access etc. The app data is held in an IndexedDB database accessed from javascript. No app data persists in the Java wrapper (to my knowledge!).
At the end of each test run, using the settings app I clear the app cache and the app data and then uninstall the app. I then run the app from Android Studio and get a new install, but the previous test data (sometimes from a few test runs ago) is still there! Very puzzled. I have even checked the "clear app storage before running" in the Android Studio run configurations.

I found a way around this. Install the app from Android Studio and as soon as it starts, stop it from Android Studio. Then from the Settings App on Android, clear the data and restart the app.
